# How to use a derived database name in Spring (Boot) Data MongoDB?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

In a Spring Boot (2.5.x, updating to 3.x is not an option right now) application with externalized (YAML) configuration, I need to have a default/fallback database name in the case where one is not specified in the YAML. The trick is that this default/fallback is derived in Java code (basically, a derivative of the host name with certain characters replaced/removed).

My first thought was to use a SpEL expression to call my method that generates the default name, but I learned that SpEL expressions are not supported in YAML config.

The POJO class where database name ends up is `MongoProperties` and that's used internally by  `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration` where it uses the properties to build a `@Bean` of type `MongoDataFactorySupport<?>`.

I tried implementing my own `@Bean` method in my `@Configuration` class, mimicing what `MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration` does, like this:

```java
@Bean
MongoDatabaseFactorySupport<?> mongoDatabaseFactory(MongoClient mongoClient) {
    return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(mongoClient, generateDatabaseName());
}
```

That doesn't work because at the time my `@Configuration` class is called, there's no `MongoClient` bean available. I started down the rabbit hole of also defining my own `MongoClient` bean, but that turned into a rabbit hole that feels too deep to accomplish something that seems like it should be simple.

Another idea I had is to intercept the populating of `MongoProperties` and insert my generated value if the provided value is blank. Seems like it should be possible to "override" a POJO `@ConfigurationProperties` class and do this, but I don't know how.

Comment: Aren't you using the configuration class derived from `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration`? Then you just override a simple method. Seems easier to just include the DB name in the Yaml though.

Comment: No, Spring Boot doesn't seem to use that config class. I *can* override it but then I have to manage more stuff that Boot's Spring Data Mongo autoconfigure does for me.

Comment: Regarding "seems eaiser to include the DB name in the Yaml," the whole point of this question is that the DB name is *derived* from the host name. If I could use SpEL in YAML config I could do that, but that isn't supported.

Comment: Yes, Spring Boot uses `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration` derived configuration. I'm using it as we speak lol. That's the documented way to custom configure Mongo. There is a `getDatabaseName()` you override.

Comment: Just for clarification you're trying to do something like "myhost-dev", "myhost-prod"? I.e. can you give an actual example of how you're generating the name?

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? I'm stuck on 2.5.x (for now) and nothing in spring-boot-autoconfigure extends `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration `

Comment: I'm in 3.x. `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration` is the user customization hook and was in the 2.x line as well. You can see here for an example of how to use it (as well as other methods of connecting) https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-connection. I do it slightly different then that article does, but its literally like 3-5 lines of code.

Comment: That class exists but Spring Boot 2.x doesn't use it. That's the problem for me; I tried extending it as I said and it resulted in me having to create most or all of the Mongo-related beans myself.

Comment: Lolz. I LITERALLY use it in both 2.x and 3.x code bases and you don't need to define ANY beans. It's LITERALLY 5 lines of code. You only override the `getDatabaseName()` and the `mongoClient()` methods. For `getDatabaseName()` you just return a string and for `mongoClient()` that's a couple of lines of code. I even sent you the link which tells you the same exact thing.